# binding image with 2 values with convertor

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

is it possiable to  set  2 data  field  for an image control whiling binding

```
**<Image Source="{Binding ItemID, Converter={StaticResource IDToImageConverter}}" Height="50" />**
```

**now here i need  to add one more value  Price now.  need  to send even price as an paramter  for  IDToImageConverter function**

how can i do it?

now i need  to check first **price value** there are  3  condition i neeed  to check

in my IDToImageConverter function

```
if( price> 5o)  
{
// then get the ItemID based on the value bind image here
if(ItemID >20)
{
// bind image1
}
if(ItemID >50)
{
// bind image2
}

}

if( price> 100)
{
// as above  codition we  do here
}
```

now  how can i add these above  functionality in  IDToImageConverter ?
 any idea how i can solve it

```
<Image Source="{Binding ItemID, Converter={StaticResource IDToImageConverter}}" Height="50" />  
</DataTemplate>  
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>  
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>  
</data:DataGrid.Columns>  
</data:DataGrid>  

public class IDToImageConverter : IValueConverter  
    {  
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
    Uri uri = new Uri("~/Images/" + value.ToString()+ ".jpg", UriKind.Relative);  
    return new BitmapImage(uri);  
    }
```

thanks in advance. for anyhelp you provide
prince

Answer (score 0):

out of the box, this is not possible. MultiBinding is not supported in SL and the ConverterParameter option is not bindable (otherwise, you could do something like Source={Binding ItemID, Converter={...}, ConverterParameter={Binding Price}} - but as I said, that's not possible).

IMHO, the best solution would be to provide an ImageUrl property in your ViewModel/data object that you can bind to:

```
public Uri ImageUrl
{
  get
  {
    if (Price > 50)
    {
      if (ItemID > 20)
        return new Uri("...");
      //...
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

If that's not an option, you could try the MultiBinding workaround described here:
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/

Cheers, Alex